# Lambda remove words from string

Tags: python, lambda

Been trying to get my head around why this is not working:

```
command = "What's the weather like in London?"
words = ["in", "like"]

command = command.replace("?", "").split('weather')[1].split(", ")
command = ",".join(filter(lambda x: x not in words, command))

print(command)
```

Output:

```
 like in London
```

I don't think the lambda function is doing what I anticipated it would, and no amount of tweaking can yield the correct result. I'm trying to extract only the word 'London'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the value of `command` before you pass it to `filter`, then think about what value `x` takes on at each step of the call to `filter`.

Comment: Hint: the lambda expression is fine, but you aren't filtering the correct iterable.

Comment: Your first 3 lines result to this:
    `[' like in London']`    Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your 3d line by this:

```
command = command.replace("?", "").split('weather')[1].split()  #remove ", " from split
```

Result will be 'London'

The reason is because your .split(", ") doesn't actually split the text but it saves it as one element in a list (which cannot be joined correctly in next command)

Answer (score 1):

You're splitting it wrong, here's an efficient way to do it:

```
command = "What's the weather like in London?"

command = "".join([x for x in command.replace("?", "").split('weather')[1].split(" ") if x not in ["in", "like"]])

print(command)
```

output:

```
London
```